# Simple process loader memory mapping

Tags: c++, linux, process, virtual-memory, memory-mapping

I'm writing a very simple process loader for Linux. The executables I'm loading are already compiled, and I know where each one expects to be found in memory. The first approach I tried was using `mmap()` to manually place each code or data section at the correct location, like

```
mmap(addr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, -1, 0)
```

which segfaults unless I remove the MAP_FIXED flag because, it seems, the address of one block conflicts with something already in memory, possibly even the loader itself; the address `0x401000` seems to be the problematic one.

I'm not really even sure where to begin with this one. A friend suggested virtualizing memory access operations; I'm not sure what kind of performance hits I'd take for that, and I have no clue how it's done, but it might be an option. What I'd really love to do is create an "empty" process, which would have, as far as it was concerned, full run of the memory, so nothing would be loaded into the user space until I wanted it to be. The whole concept of an "empty" process might be meaningless, but it's the best way to describe what I want. I'm pretty desperate for some references or examples that might help me.

Comment: "create an "empty" process" this process has some code and data, and those have to reside somewhere. Do you really need whole address space? Perhaps there is some are of the address space you can assume the processes you are loading will never take?

Comment: It's hard to say, really... I wanted it to be as flexible as possible so any address would be valid.

Comment: How is what you want to do different from `exec`?

Comment: @MarkB I do want to transition to a new process, but I want to load the instructions and data into memory _manually_. `exec` would just run an executable, which wouldn't be much of a process loader.

Comment: Why are you doing that? and do you want to alter the kernel?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There's a few reasons I'm working on this. It's interesting, for one, and I'm learning a lot about memory management and the kernel, but it's also part of a larger project with the goal of seamlessly executing an EXE. I really don't want to alter the kernel, though.

Comment: Wine is probably already doing this, learn about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know about Wine, but I don't want to use it for this application. I'd want to do something like `:DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/bin/my_app:` if I used this.

Comment: Does the `mmap()` actually segfault or did you forget to check its return value and `errno` then?

Comment: @MichałGórny The `mmap()` actually segfaults. When I stepped through the code in `gdb` it crashed on the line with `mmap()`. I never tried to use the address it returned.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars Are you loading statically linked applications ? Dynamically linked ones take a whole lot of effort and fixups to do, as you have to load the dependant shared libraries and perform the proper relocation

Comment: @nos I'm not really even to that level yet... I'm only testing on applications that don't link to anything right now. The code I'm testing with right now is just `mov eax, 4; add eax, 5; ret` compiled with `fasm`. I'd like to eventually get to the point where I could load both dynamically and statically linked applications, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars: well, I was able to reproduce it but looking at the manpage, I don't see any mentioning that it should segfault in this case. I suggest you tried reporting a bug against glibc.

Comment: @MichałGórny I might do that, but I'm not really concerned about the segfault itself; I'm pretty sure, based on another question I've asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691595/mapping-multiple-data-arrays-to-arbitrary-fixed-memory-addresses), that something is already loaded to that address. Right now, I just want to find a way to do the manual loading in an empty process space where that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

With your process running (maybe snoozing in "sleep(1000);"), look at its /proc/pid/maps. That will tell you what 0x401000 is used for.

```
~$ sleep 1h &
[3] 2033
~$ cat /proc/2033/maps
00110000-002af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1313056    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
...
```

Here on my box, /bin/sleep doesn't use that block, and neither does my little one-liner program.

You're probably linking in some library which wants to land there?

So one way would be to allocate the block you need way early (long before main() runs -- look elsewhere for that info).

Another way is to link your code to some address you "know" isn't taken (presumably, you're generating the x86 opcodes yourself, or otherwise "linking", so that shouldn't be a stretch).

Another, better, option is to make your code relocatable. The fact that you don't want to replace the entire process's address space (precisely what exec does) more or less says that your code should be just that.

So find a usable address, load the bits there, and, as needed, perform the relocations (so your on-disk file format, if it's not ELF, will need to include reloc info). That's the high road, and the obvious thing you'll want next from your loader.

Of course, that pretty much means reimplementing dlopen() yourself. I assume you're just trying to learn how it works -- if not, man dlopen. Stephane's Rule Zero: it's already there ;-)

Don't forget to support linking other libraries from your code (without duplication), dlclose(), initializers, the various RTLD_* modes, honor MYCUSTOMLD_LIBRARY_PATH, GCC's __thread specifier, etc. ;-)