# Linux process loader in C++

Tags: c++, linux, process, linux-kernel

I'm working on a process loader for a Linux platform in C++; it's just a recreational project. Basically, I would like to load all the sections of an executable into memory manually and then execute it.

I asked a related but more specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723758/simple-process-loader-memory-mapping) about a week ago. However, after doing more reading, I realized that memory mapping will be irrelevant until I learn how to actually create the process. So my question is, is there a way to create a "blank" new process on Linux with its own virtual address space (which I will be able to access to load in the code and data)?

Even general resources on process loader development would be useful, since I have yet to find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested to see what the Linux process loader is really doing behind the scenes when you ask it to `exec()` something, grab a copy of the kernel source and look inside `fs/exec.c` for `do_execve_common()`.

The ELF handler itself, which ends up being called if you're trying to run an ELF binary, lives in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`. In particular, `load_elf_binary()` does the actual loading given a `struct linux_binprm` containing the necessary information to load the process image from disk.

Observe that there are many `binfmt_*.c` files for the binary formats that Linux supports; if you had a custom binary format, then you *could*, in principle, write your own and provide it as a kernel module. The internals of process loading are opaque to user-mode code (and rightfully so: serious security holes would exist if not).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the fork() function to create a new process which will create the replica of the parent process, then using one of the [exec](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/execv/) family function you can load your executable and execute it.

Comment: I need the process virtual space to be empty, though. If the new process is a replica of the old one, then that won't work. The loader and executable need to be independent of each other once loading is complete.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars this is just how unix-like operating systems work.  The exec functions do wipe the slate clean, but then they auto fill it with the target executable.  You can replace the dynamic library linker functionality, but the kernel is going to do your basic static loading.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The executables I'm loading aren't ELF, though; that's why I need to load the sections manually.

Comment: You still have to start with one of the small number of file types the kernel knows how to initialize a process from; after that you can do whatever custom loading you want.

Comment: You may need to implement ur own loader or u need to make it ELF so that some existing loader can load it.